# Reversing the word order in a string in place

Tags: c, string, algorithm

I'm trying to reverse the order of words in a sentence in place, eg:

> This sentences words are reversed.

becomes

> reversed. are words sentences This

This is what I have so far, which almost works:
I use the strrev function to reverse the string, and then the inprev function to send each word to the strrev function individually, to reverse them back to the original orientation, but in reversed order.
Sending a pointer for the start and end of the strrev function might seem a bit silly, but it allows the same function to be used in inprev(), sending off a pointer to the start and end of individual words.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void strrev(char * start, char * end);
void inprev(char * start);

int main(void)
{
   char str[] = "Foobar my friends, foobar";
   char * end = (str + strlen(str) -1);
   puts(str);
   strrev(str, end);
   puts(str);
   inprev(str);

   puts(str);

   return 0;
}

void strrev(char * start, char * end)
{
   char temp;

while (end > start)
   {
     temp = *start;
     *start = *end;
     *end = temp;
      start++;
      end--;
   }
}

void inprev(char * start)
{
     char * first = start;
     char * spcpnt = start;
     while (*spcpnt)
     {
        while (*spcpnt != ' ' && *spcpnt)
           spcpnt++;
        strrev(start, spcpnt-1);         // removing the -1 sends the space on the 
        start = spcpnt++;                // other side to be reversed, doesn't stop 
                                         // the problem.  

     }

}
```

Here is the output:

> Foobar my friends, foobar
>
> raboof ,sdneirf ym rabooF
>
> foobarfriends, my Foobar

The problem is that the lack of a final space at the end of the final word means that a space is missing between that word and the preceeding one in the final string, and instead gets thrown onto the end of the last word, which was the first word in the original string. Sending off the space on the other side of the word only moves the problem elsewhere. Can anyone see a solution?

Comment: What are you supposed to do when you encounter X spaces? Do they belong to the word before or after?

Comment: +1 nice problem :). If I'll have a little time I will provide a solution

Comment: I guess you dont want to extra make the first letter a big one, as your example shows...

Comment: @RedX Didn't think of that, I'll have another look at my algorithm and try to think of something

Comment: @imacake correct, typo. thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to move the `start` pointer in the `inprev` function to skip the space between words. As this appears to be homework (correct me if I'm wrong) I'll just say that all you need to do is move the location of one operator.

But, this produces a problem, namely, the `inprev` performs a buffer overrun because the search isn't terminated properly. A better way to do it is:

```
while not end of string
  search for start of word
  start = start of word
  search for end of word
  strrev (start, end)
```

and that will take care of multiple spaces too. Also, U+0020 (ASCII 32, a space) is not the only white space character. There are standard library functions that test characters. They are in <ctype.h> and start with `is...`, e.g. `isspace`.

Comment: Thanks! Updated original question with my fixed algorithm. Not homework btw, saw it in a job interview question prep and thought I'd have a crack at it for fun.

Comment: @Matt Please don't fix the original code in the question! That makes the question useless for anyone who reads it in the future. I will rollback that edit.

Comment: @Matt: to add to razlebe's comment, you can post the updated code as an answer, rather than editing the question.

Comment: @Matt - No harm done. :) Easily rolled back. I agree with Skizz though - it'd be great if you could post your fixed code as an answer to help future readers to completely understand the fix.

Comment: @razlebe: Will do, I've gotta wait 5 hours though, apparently.

Comment: Improved function posted, if anyone is interested.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes things get easier if you don't use pointers but offsets.
The strspn() and strcspn() library functions more or less force you to use offsets,
and deal with the end-of-string condition quite nicely.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

size_t revword(char *str);
void revmem(void *ptr, size_t len);

size_t revword(char *str) {
size_t pos,len;

for (pos=len=0; str[pos]; pos += len) {
        len = strspn( str+pos, " \t\n\r");
        if (len) continue;
        len = strcspn( str+pos, " \t\n\r");
        if (!len) continue;
        revmem( str+pos, len );
        }
revmem( str, pos );
return len;
}

void revmem(void *ptr, size_t len)
{
size_t idx;
char *str = (char*) ptr;

if (len-- < 2) return;

for (idx = 0; idx < len; idx++,len--) {
        char tmp = str[idx];
        str[idx] = str[len];
        str[len] = tmp;
        }
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{

if (!argv[1]) return 0;
revword(argv[1] );
printf("'%s'\n", argv[1] );

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Would you be able to add a few comments to this explaining what's happening? It's a bit hard to follow, for example, what's happening in the revword function.

Comment: Well: in the loop, I measure the length of consecutive whitespace (the strspn() call), and skip it. After that I measure the length of consecutive *NON*whitespace (the strcspn() call) and reverse it. At the end of the loop I have the whole length of the string accumulated and reverse the whole string.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a solution; here is my revised function that works properly.

```
void inprev(char * str)
{
    _Bool inword = 0;
    char * wordend;
    char * wordstart;

     while(*str)
     {
         if(!isspace(*str) && (inword == 0))
         {
             wordstart = str;
             inword = 1;
         }
         else if (isspace(*str) && (inword == 1))
         {
             wordend = str-1;
             inword = 0;
             strrev(wordstart, wordend);
         }

         str++;
     }

     if (*str == '\0')
        strrev(wordstart, str-1);

}
```

char * wordend is uneccessary as you can just pass str-1 to the strrev function, but it makes it a bit more clear what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

The following algorithm is in-place and runs in 2 steps. First it reverses the entire string. Then it reverses each word.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void reverse(char *str, int len)
{
    char *p = str;
    char *e = str + len - 1;

    while (p != e) {
        *p ^= *e ^= *p ^= *e;
        p++;
        e--;
    }
}

void reverse_words(char *str)
{
    char *p;

    // First, reverse the entire string
    reverse(str, strlen(str));

    // Then, reverse each word
    p = str;
    while (*p) {
        char *e = p;
        while (*e != ' ' && *e != '\0') {
            e++;
        }

        reverse(p, e - p);
        printf("%.*s%c", e - p, p, *e);

        if (*e == '\0')
            break;
        else
            p = e + 1;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    char buf[] = "Bob likes Alice";
    reverse_words(buf);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If `len` is even, the function `reverse` will cause a segfault. Try `while (p < e)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
void reverse_str(char* const p, int i, int j) // helper to reverse string p from index i to j
{
    char t;
    for(; i < j ; i++, j--)
        t=p[i], p[i]=p[j], p[j]=t;
}

void reverse_word_order(char* const p) // reverse order of words in string p
{
    int i, j, len = strlen(p);  // use i, j for start, end indices of each word

    reverse_str(p, 0, len-1);      // first reverse the whole string p
    for(i = j = 0; i < len; i = j) // now reverse chars in each word of string p
    {
        for(; p[i] && isspace(p[i]);) // advance i to word begin
            i++;
        for(j = i; p[j] && !isspace(p[j]);) // advance j to past word end
            j++;
        reverse_str(p, i, j-1);  // reverse chars in word between i, j-1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is almost correct except for the line `start = spcpnt++;`
Change this to `start = ++spcpnt;` and it works.
the original assignment was copying the character and then incrementing the pointer. So, `start` was pointing to space instead of the first character of the next string.
Note that there is a difference between increment operation with no assignment to assignment to another variable with increment operation!

Here is the full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void strrev(char * start, char * end);
void inprev(char * start);

void strrev(char * start, char * end)
{
    char temp;
    
    while (end > start)
    {
        temp = *start;
        *start = *end;
        *end = temp;
        start++;
        end--;
    }
}

void inprev(char * start)
{
    char * spcpnt = start;
    while (*spcpnt)
    {
        while (!isspace(*spcpnt) && *spcpnt)
        {
            spcpnt++;
        }
        
        strrev(start, spcpnt-1);
        
        start = ++spcpnt;
    }

}

int main(void)
{
   char str[] = "Foobar my friends, foobar";
   
   char * end = (str + strlen(str) -1);
   puts(str);
   
   strrev(str, end);
   puts(str);
   
   inprev(str);
   puts(str);

   return 0;
}
```

The output for this program is:

```
Foobar my friends, foobar
raboof ,sdneirf ym rabooF
foobar friends, my Foobar
```